# Ionic platform events not working

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, ionic-framework

This worked fine until today, don't know does it have something with new release of Ionic or something else.
This is what i have:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
  }

  if (window.StatusBar) {
    // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
    StatusBar.styleDefault();
  }

  $ionicPlatform.on('pause', function(){
    alert("pause");
    $rootScope.$broadcast('app-pause', {});
    $rootScope.$emit('app-pause', {});
  })

  $ionicPlatform.on('resume', function(){
    alert("resume");
  })

  $ionicPlatform.on('online', function(){
    alert("online");
  })

  $ionicPlatform.$on('offline', function(){
    alert("offline");
  })

});
```

None of these events work anymore. I have updated Cordova and Ionic but also added network-information plugin but nothing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use cordova way doing this

```
var exampleApp = angular.module('example', ['ionic'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        document.addEventListener("resume", function() {
            console.log("The application is resuming from the background");
        }, false);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, actually i solved it using codova way. But still it's strange it worked before. Thanks.

Comment: non of those are working for me. Cordova or Ionic way

Answer (score 4):

You can try not wrapping it inside the platform ready event, the following is working for me on Android with version 1.3.0. Sitting inside app run.

```
    $ionicPlatform.on("resume", function(){
       setTimeout(function() {
           alert('doc resume 5');
       }, 0);
    });
```

Comment: Worked for me. An ionic way. :)